# What's the small 1M partition that goes before the EFI partition?

Tags: partition, disk, partition-table

I'm seeing that all my EFI disks have a 1M partition that goes just before the the EFI partition:

```
Device       Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sda1       34       2047       2014 1007K BIOS boot
/dev/sda2     2048    1050623    1048576  512M EFI System
/dev/sda3  1050624        ...
```

I have tried to mount that partition to explore it but I haven't been able nor I have been able to find information online.

What's the purpose of this partition and what's inside?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a [BIOS boot partition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIOS_boot_partition). It is the "legacy" method to boot your system – with EFI being the "new" method. EFI systems ignore this partition.

The legacy boot method usually employs a MBR and its partition table. However, disks larger than 2 TB are usually formatted with GPT. Some users want a way to use the legacy boot method with a big disk. The GPT uses the BIOS boot partition to make explicit where the legacy bootloader shall be stored. GRUB is a notable example. This partition has no file-system, hence it cannot be mounted.